# When is a event listener invoked during program execution?

Tags: java, programming-practices, interfaces, event-programming

I am using the Obervable-Observer Pattern.

```
MyClass extends Observable{

  invokeListeners(){
     doSomething;
     setChanged();
     notifyListeners();//This invokes onUpdate() in "implements Observer" 

     return value;
  }
}

ClassTwo implements Observer{

   onUpdate(){
      //This is called after notifyListeners();
   }
}
```

My question is when will the `onUpdate` method in the Listener Class get invoked? After the `invokeListeners()` methods completes, or right after `notifyListeners()`?

Comment: With reference to the docs of Java [7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html), [8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) and [9](http://download.java.net/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) - shouldn't it be `notifyObservers()` ?

Comment: Please refer to Telastyn or Halter's answer. That is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

In the Implementation of

`notifyListeners();//This invokes onUpdate() in "implements Observer"`

is normally a loop over all registered Observers.

In this loop is normally a direct call to

```
onUpdate()
```

on each registered Observer.

Be sure not to block the execution in the implementation of

```
onUpdate()
```

Comment: So the method invokeListeners() is finished executing after all the update() methods in the observer are executed.

Answer (score 2):

In general, `notifyListeners` is implemented as a list of delegates/observers which are just plain old functions that get called in order. So the observer functions will generally be invoked *during* the `notifyListeners` call (like your comment implies).

There are different possible implementations, some that run in parallel in background threads, some that send the request off to a queue, but the direct call is the most common.

Comment: Which is the most common implementation? Direct Call? And how is the order of listeners decided?

Comment: @akshayrajkore - yes direct call. Generally by order of addition to the event.

Comment: Thanks. I would have upvoted your answer, but I require 10 reputation.

Comment: @akshayrajkore Keep in mind though, that the listener order is implementation-dependent and not guaranteed. Depending on a particular order is probably a bad idea, the structure containing the listeners map be something like a tree or set, where no guarantees are made about traversal order.

Answer (score 0):

To check the stacktrace, I incremented a static int in the update() method of all the listeners.

I added a System.out.println() in the method where I call notifyListeners() and in the update() methods of the listeners to see the value of the static. Following is stacktrace values -

public static int observer = 0; //Initialized

StackTrace :
After NotifyListeners : 0
In update() : 1
In update() : 2
In update() : 3

This implies that the method in which notifyListeners() call is placed, first completes its execution and after that the update() methods in the Observer are called in a loop.